# failed to connect to all addresses grpc in python

Tags: python-3.x, grpc, grpc-python

I am trying to post data to arangodb using grpc and using script below but while running the client getting above error , My server is running in a good way,unable to figure out where is the error

```
from inspect import trace
import re
from urllib import response
import grpc
import os
import first_pb2_grpc as pb2_grpc
import first_pb2 as pb2
import json
import grpc
from typing import Dict, List
from google.protobuf import json_format 
from first_pb2_grpc import*
import traceback
test_data_file_name = "data.json"
curr_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))

test_data_file = os.path.join(curr_dir,test_data_file_name)
def read_json_file(file):
    with open(file, encoding="utf8") as f:
        data = json.load(f)
    return data

test_data = read_json_file(test_data_file)

channel = grpc.insecure_channel('localhost:31024')

stub = pb2_grpc.UnaryStub(channel)

def test(request):
    try:
        response = stub.GetServerResponse(request)
        print(response , 'AAAAA')
        return response
    except Exception as e:
        return str(e)

def test_add_name(message):
    try:
        request = pb2.Message(
            message=message
        )
        test_response = test(request)
        
        return test_response
    except Exception as e:
        traceback.print_exc()
        return str(e)



if __name__ == "__main__":
    message = test_data["message"]
    #attribute_val = json_format.Parse(json.dumps(name) , message='hi') 
    api_response = test_add_name(message)
    print(api_response)
```

Please tell me how can i resolve this

Comment: It could be for any number of reasons. Is arangodb listening on localhost, or just 127.0.0.1? Does it accept connections? Is there a firewall? I recommend to double check the server. Try to connect to it with another tool, f.e. grpcurl